# Non-Linear readings on Analog Pin A0 vs. other Pins A1

Tags: arduino-nano, pins, adc

I discovered a curios behavior of my Nano v3. The analog Pin A0 seems to measure data in a non-linear way while the other pins seem to work normal.

Please have a look at the screenshot. This is the normal ReadAnalogVoltage example with a 50K potentiometer. A1 (red line) raise and falls linear when turning the knob. But the A0 line (blue) does not.

[image]

Is there a way to change it back to the normal behavior? Some weeks ago it worked fine on A0 as well. So these results are quite surprising for me. In general it would have been easy using another pin, but I already created a pcb which utilize A0.

Thanks

Comment: Does this happen within your circuit, or does it happen on a nano that is just connected to pots? Also what is the code stamped on the pot?

Comment: It is the official Arduino example: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ReadAnalogVoltage

My circuit uses an audio sensor for clap detection. It wasn't triggering anymore, that is why stumbled upon it. So this happens to both: the nano directly connected to a poti and my circuit.

Comment: When Arduino is not powered, measure resistance between failing pin and 5V/GND pins